# how to set an expanding animation to a searchview

Tags: android, searchview, searchbar

I want to set an expanding animation to a searchview and I try to apply the method that I found:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    final int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);
    LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(searchBarId);
    searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
    return true;
}
```

However, the variable searchBar is always null and it always crashes at the line

```
searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

I don't know what is causing the error. Can someboby help me out? Thanks!

Comment: did you get any solution ???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out that you get null in your `searchBar` if you use `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

I changed it to `android.widget.SearchView` (recommended if supporting api > 11). Now I get the needed linear layout and animation works fine.

**Edit**

If you need a support version, you have to use proper id: `LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) mFilterInput.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_bar);`